# Controlling an embedded user interface

Tags: user-interface, embedded, hardware, state

I am busy with a small project that allows for the controlling of an embedded hardware user interface to be moved from state charts and simple constructs as if .. else to a more visual representation.

I would now like to begin testing on a real project. I am looking for an open source hardware project. I've searched around but I have not been able to find anything that meets my requirements.

1/ hardware and software publicly available (i'm don't mind having to buy something)

2/ written in C/C++

3/ has graphical user interface

Any ideas?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might take a look at the open source QP state machine frameworks, which are also supported by the free graphical modeling tool called QM (state-machine.com). QP run on many embedded MCUs, including Arduino and mbed rapid prototyping platforms. The webstie contains a lot of information, including using statecharts for embedded GUIs.

Answer (score 0):

**[This](http://www.lazarus.freepascal.org/index.php/topic,17688.msg98008.html)** is not C++ but free with sources and might give you an idea:

[image: TStateMachine]

If made to work on Linux, it may be combined with **[fpGUI](http://fpgui.sourceforge.net) [on ARM](http://www.turbocontrol.com/easyfpgui.htm)**.